# Swapping two elemnts in android

Tags: android, image, swap, element

I have been trying to find an example of what i want to do to guide myself, but i could not.
I want to use a `Grid` and place images in every "cell". Until here, i got to do it.

After, i want to swap the images with long clicks. 
**This means i want to drag one image and drop it into the place of another image, and this second image would take the place of the first image.**

Could anyone try to guide me, or tell a hint to start and proceed?

I have tried a version where i store the images in an `ArrayList`. This way i could do what i wanted just by swapping the elements in the `list` and displaying (working with `list`s looks much easier that working with `view`s...).
But i dont want to use an `ArrayList`. Is possible? Is it logical?

I hope i explained myself enough good.

Edited:
This is what i have figure out so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnDragListener,
        OnItemLongClickListener {

    ArrayList drawables;

    private BaseAdapter adapter;
    private int draggedIndex = -1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        drawables = new ArrayList();
        drawables.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        drawables.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        drawables.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        drawables.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        drawables.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        drawables.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        drawables.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        drawables.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(MainActivity.this);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter = new BaseAdapter() { //some methods here...}

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView gridView, View view,
            int position, long row) {
        ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((String) view.getTag());
        ClipData clipData = new ClipData((CharSequence) view.getTag(),
                new String[] { ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN }, item);
        view.startDrag(clipData, new View.DragShadowBuilder(view), null, 0);

        !!!!!!!!! setOnDragListener(MainActivity.this);


        draggedIndex = position;
        return true;
    }
```

My logic says that for the view to be dragged, I call "startDrag".

but what about "setOnDragListener"?  what view should i specify?  in fact, i cannot really specify one view, because i can swap the dragged view with any other...

thanks a lot in advance for your time, hopefully i can get some light!

Comment: Hi! Maybe you can have a look at https://github.com/askerov/DynamicGrid and use this library or at least see how he's doing it.

Comment: I have done that, but it is really complex for my level, super n00b here T.T